# What does *New() mean when declaring member function?

Tags: c++, class, vtk

I'm working on a VTK program and have found a class (specifically this one: [Image Region](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/ImageRegion)) which i need to incorporate into my code. To do so I have made a separate ImageRegion.h and ImageRegion.cpp files so they can be easily included in the project.  My Problem here is the

> static vtkBorderCallback *New()

function which i do not know how to implement in the .cpp file or, to be quite honest, what purpose it serves at all. What does it do? Is it even necessary to have it?

When compiling I get the error:

> /home/Desktop/test/src/ImageRegion.cpp:7:10: error: ‘vtkBorderCallback::vtkBorderCallback’ names the constructor, not the type

My .h file:

```
//ImageRegion.h
#pragma once

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkAssemblyNode.h>
#include <vtkAssemblyPath.h>
#include <vtkBorderRepresentation.h>
#include <vtkCommand.h>
#include <vtkCoordinate.h>
#include <vtkImageMapper3D.h>
#include <vtkImageActor.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleImage.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkPropPicker.h>
#include <vtkProperty2D.h>
#include <vtkBorderWidget.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>

class vtkBorderCallback : public vtkCommand
{
public:
  vtkBorderCallback();
  static vtkBorderCallback *New();
  virtual void Execute(vtkObject *caller, unsigned long, void*);
  void SetRenderer(vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> ren);
  void SetImageActor(vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> im);
  double coords[6];



private:
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> Renderer;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> ImageActor;

};
```

And my .cpp file:

```
//ImageRegion.cpp
#include "ImageRegion.h"


  vtkBorderCallback::vtkBorderCallback(){}


  static vtkBorderCallback::vtkBorderCallback* New()   
    {
    return new vtkBorderCallback;
    }

  void vtkBorderCallback::Execute(vtkObject *caller, unsigned long, void*)
    {
      //Do stuff, from original VTK example code
    }

  void vtkBorderCallback::SetRenderer(vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> ren) {this->Renderer = ren;}
  void vtkBorderCallback::SetImageActor(vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> im) {this->ImageActor = im;}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
static vtkBorderCallback *New();
```

is a `static` member function called `New`, taking no arguments, and returning a pointer to `vtkBorderCallback`.

In the implementation, you should omit the `static`. You also need to place the function in the scope of its class:

```
vtkBorderCallBack*  vtkBorderCallback::New()
{//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return new vtkBorderCallback; // danger! Caller needs to delete this eventually
}
```

Comment: How should I correctly implement it in my ImageRegion.cpp file?

Comment: @user2746425 I have added an example.

Answer (score 3):

In VTK nearly all of the classes derive from vtkObjectBase. They should use New() and Delete() to create and delete the objects (the constructor and destructor are protected). These methods include referencing counting to make sure that they get properly shared among other vtkObjects that may use them. There is a VTK macro (vtkStandardNewMacro) that takes care of the implementation of New() and the base class implements Delete(). So for VTK, the best way to implement the static New() method is to use that macro. For your class called vtkBorderCallBack it would look like:

> vtkStandardNewMacro(vtkBorderCallBack);

This should go in your .cpp file.

Comment: I believe that you also have to include in your *.cpp file this header:                            #include "vtkObjectFactory.h" //for new() macro

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error, put `vtkBorderCallBack::` before `New()`:

```
vtkBorderCallBack* vtkBorderCallBack::New()   
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

He should not omit `static` since `New()` is meant as constructor. In this scenario I would rather expect the real constructor to be `private`. The implementation

```
 static vtkBorderCallback::vtkBorderCallBack* New()   
    {
    return new vtkBorderCallback;
    }
```

is syntactically wrong. It has so be

```
 vtkBorderCallBack* vtkBorderCallback::New()   
    {
    return new vtkBorderCallback;
    }
```

Finally the whole approach is strange. `New()` is not really required here, and possibly leads to a memory leak. To establish a class-specific memory management overload operators `new` and `delete` on a per-class basis. Alternatively, to prevent leaks, do not return a raw pointer; return `std::auto_ptr` (deprecated) or `std::unique_ptr`:

```
 std::unique_ptr<vtkBorderCallBack> vtkBorderCallback::New()   
    {
    return std::unique_ptr<vtkBorderCallBack>(new vtkBorderCallback); // uses move c'tor
    }
```

However, `std::unique_ptr`s are movable but not copyable. But that's the point when leaks have to be prevented. When the pointer returned by `New()` is spreaded all over the code better use a `std::shared_ptr`.

If you have only a C++03 compiler I recommend Herb Sutter's [Using auto_ptr Effectively](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm).

Comment: It seems a bit strange to me too, but I haven't done much c++ programming so I don't know what might be the right or wrong way for this. As long as it works like in the original example code, I guess it will suffice.

Comment: You don't need `static` in the definition, only in the declaration.

Comment: I am not sure that using c++ smart pointers with VTK will work well. VTK code + vtk macros (there is actually a macro to implement the New) expect its own smart pointers and the return type of new to be someVtkObject* not a c++ smart pointer.